# get `keyof` non-optional property names in typescript

Tags: typescript

This is my interface

```
interface X {
    key: string
    value: number | undefined
    default?: number
}
```

But I want the non-optional keys only, aka. `"key" | "value"`, or just `"key"` (both will do fine for me)

`type KeyOfX = keyof X` gives me `"key" | "value" | "default"`.

```
type NonOptionalX = {
    [P in keyof X]-?: X[P]
}
```

`type NonOptionalKeyOfX = keyof NonOptionalX` gives `"key" | "value" | "default"` as `-?` only removes the optional modifier and make all of them non-optional.

ps. I use Typescript 2.9.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You can use conditional type operator of the form `undefined extends k ? never : k` to substitute `never` for keys of values that `undefined` could be assigned to, and then use the fact that union `T | never` is just `T` for any type:

```
interface X {
    key: string
    value: number | undefined
    default?: number
}


type NonOptionalKeys<T> = { [k in keyof T]-?: undefined extends T[k] ? never : k }[keyof T];

type Z = NonOptionalKeys<X>; // just 'key'
```

Also this comment might be relevant: https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/12215#issuecomment-307871458

Answer (score 11):

> But I want the non-optional keys only, aka. "key" | "value", or just "key" (both will do fine for me)

While easier option of `"key"` is covered, I'd like to cover a less obvious option of `"key" | "value"`. It might be needed because `value` is not an *optional field*. It can be assigned `undefined`, but it should pass a `"value" in x` check.

```
type NonOptionalKeys<T> = { [K in keyof T]-?: T extends { [K1 in K]: any } ? K : never}[keyof T]
```

How it works:

- keys in mapped object types (`K`) are actually not only types, but types with "requiredness" and "readonlyness" attached;
- iteration over keys of `T` with `-?` makes optional keys required before putting them into `K`;
- `{ [K1 in K]: any }` object is an object with single required key
- if original type extends it, that key was required, we keep its name as a type of values for that key;
- optional keys don't pass the check and get collected as `never`;
- the resulting object contains names of the keys of original types as fields and either same key or `never` as value;
- with `[keyof T]` a union of all the value types gets computed, `never` types get removed (`(A | never) = A`), and only a union of all required keys is left.

Update: `readonly` is way trickier. Read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52473108/1872046) or [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49579497/1872046). You can completely disassemble an object into a tuple [like this](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.1.5#code/C4TwDgpgBAkgZgUQI4FcCGAbAzgHgBoA0UAmkQIJEBCAfFALxQAUOAKtYwJT20tQQAewCADsAJlih4oAfigBGKAC4oAJi4ChYiczaduUXhpHiSM%20UtVdZZC5QDcAKFCQoAJQhpRAe2EYQAaQgQXABVIl4GAG8oAG1-KABLYSgAayCvOCgQgF0AWmllELjsqABfWiiHKFiABUTktJAMg2zleGR0bBxomIBFeqga1oMYobKiaNyAJw9vXxBY-qTB4ZZRktKiYQgANwgpohrqB1KYxuaWbMdnaAAxFAwMViJXejdZnz9A4NZqCqhIlUoNMPvNYvFludMpd8spAdVqjdlGt-NkCEDql4wMAEj5MMi%20IJjBJ3ABjLxTUQ4fxENDCEC0WRwTBYaDKYBTFAQdEIqAzTyfEDKeJGLRuMwcrkWZnYblA0onJzgaAhYRwFCklK-N6GIlipJwfbi2SROIDKFuYauYqlCzbPZTa7KgwQLDAbVRNAFKB0kC20UmHoQhrpaE%20iQAcjQEdWxTKZgjACM0FMIxYI3AvF4I0qXLcElM3TgQv94eDzaGsuGXUWaimcZhi7QAGSDBKa4tEfx-Yb%20E6EzSBzNeZQGo2uW2yV7KOS56AAEVdpKmCUTEBgQimz3FDHzhfdbH%20rwDEjdK%20EAHMgbJdYOSRByZScK5afTjrzZDEMQjVeqO5FhDQABbCBlAnKBWzWVxsmoHleSgAA6JDFywZdV3XTdizVDUtQAeSAhIDxeP53wRbJv2Ue19iBZQYnIm4oBQtC1w9RilxXNcN32HB7keX5jjnHc2NQjiIG6IEvUolAgLXA4oCBRNlDPJILyIIF%20TmPwoFJZREyzDAPGENTqg0wUoFEb0IwgCN0XKBwgA).

Comment: The only downside of this kind of filter is lost the compiler error showing the keys strings when use `keyof T` to get all object keys. But the error still clear: `Type '"foo"' is not assignable to type 'NonOptionalKeys<Bar>'`