# What is the difference between Record<K, T> and { [key: K]: T } in TypeScript?

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

Hi what's the difference between `Record<K, T>` and `{ [key: K]: T }` in TypeScript?
For example they seem to work the same in the below code.

```js
const obj1: Record<string, number> = {a: 1, b: 2};
const obj2: { [key: string]: number } = {a: 1, b: 2};
```

Is there any difference between them?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Difference between index signature and Record for empty object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54100025/difference-between-index-signature-and-record-for-empty-object)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

No difference in your case, but it is possible to do more with `Record`. Consider the [official example](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#recordkeys-type)

```
interface CatInfo {
  age: number;
  breed: string;
}
 
type CatName = "miffy" | "boris" | "mordred";
 
const cats: Record<CatName, CatInfo> = {
  miffy: { age: 10, breed: "Persian" },
  boris: { age: 5, breed: "Maine Coon" },
  mordred: { age: 16, breed: "British Shorthair" },
};
```

You cannot replace it with

```
const cats2: {[key:CatName]: CatInfo} = {
    miffy: { age: 10, breed: "Persian" },
    boris: { age: 5, breed: "Maine Coon" },
    mordred: { age: 16, breed: "British Shorthair" },
};
```

because this gives you error `An index signature parameter type cannot be a literal type or generic type. Consider using a mapped object type instead.(1337)`

Comment: That rings a bell... I've actually seen such error many times previously. I guess `Record` type works more intuitively and that's why we should use it. Thanks!

Comment: Btw @ricky-mo, do you think there is any case that we should use `{ [key: K]: T }` instead? I think we can always prefer `Record` in modern TypeScript; is it correct?

Comment: It is totally up to preference and debatable.

Comment: `{ [key: K]: T }` defines the key of the object `has type K (key is K)` (either string or number), while `Record<K,T>` defines the key of the object is `within the set K (key in K)`. When `K` is `string` or `number` or any non-literal types, the "set" happens to be an infinite set and hence function the same. Using `Record<K,T>` with unbounded `string` or `number` seems to make less sense because saying `K is a number` is more concise than saying `K is one of these numbers, while these numbers is all numbers`.

Comment: okay the question you mentioned above appears to contain good discussions. I'll read them, thanks!

Comment: hmm interesting. I didn't know there are such implications for both types. You mean most people with plenty of TS knowledge will find `Record<K,T>` with non-literal type `K` unnatural, right?

Comment: I can't represent most people (I don't even know what most people think). I just try to come up with one possible argument. As I said it is up to preference and debatable. After all it doesn't matter as long as it functions the same.

Comment: One more on my personal thoughts. I feel `Record<K,T>` sound like some custom data type I may happen to have in my codebase. I mean I could have totally design a custom data model which one of the elements name "Record" or something similar. Having a type name `Record<K,T>` here and there may easily trick me.

Comment: That makes sense. Both points sound reasonable to me. Since I just get to know Record type recently, I'll try them and begin to establish my preference. Thank you for taking your time to answer this question!