# Typescript conditional validation depending on field nullability

Tags: typescript

I do have the following code:

```
type DomainFieldDefinition<T> = {
  required?: boolean
}

type DomainDefinition<F, M> = {
  fields?: { [K in keyof F]: DomainFieldDefinition<F[K]> },
  methods?: { [K in keyof M]: M[K] & Function },
}

type User = {
  id: string,
  name?: string
}

export const User = createDomain<User>({
  fields: {
    id: { required: true },
    name: {},
  },
});
```

I am trying to validate that the `required` key in the definition object passed to the `createDomain` method for a field has a value that matches the requiredness of the type it is based on (here, `User`) ; ideally at compile time.

I have the sensation that conditional types may help in doing so, but I could not find a way to do so based on requiredness. Specifically, I'm trying to constrain `required` to be:

- `true` if the field is not nullable,
- `false` or undefined if it is

Any hints?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the types defined [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49579094/typescript-conditional-types-filter-out-readonly-properties-pick-only-requir/49579497#49579497)  as an example we can create a conditional type where if the field is required `field` type will be of type `{ required : true }` or `{}` otherwise:

```
type DomainDefinition<F, M> = {
    fields?: {
        [K in keyof F]: ({} extends { [P in K]: F[K] } ? {} : { required: true }) & {} // Intersect with other properties as necessary
    },
    methods?: { [K in keyof M]: M[K] & Function },
}

type User = {
    id: string,
    name?: string
}

function createDomain<T>(o: DomainDefinition<T, any>) {
    return o;
}

export const User = createDomain<User>({
    fields: {
        id: { required: true },
        name: {},
    },
});
```

**Note** This will test for optionality (the `?` modifier) it will not test for nullability ( `| null | undefined`) depending on your use case this may or may not be important.

Also of interest may be [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52443276/how-to-exclude-getter-only-properties-from-type-in-typescript/52473108#52473108) answer that has a test for the `readonly` modifier. Using it, you can also add a `isReadonly` field:

```
type IfEquals<X, Y, A, B> =
    (<T>() => T extends X ? 1 : 2) extends
(<T>() => T extends Y ? 1 : 2) ? A : B;

type DomainDefinition<F, M> = {
    fields?: {
        [K in keyof F]:
        ({} extends { [P in K]: F[P] } ? {} : { required: true })
        & IfEquals<{ [P in K]: F[P] }, { -readonly [P in K]: F[P] }, {}, { isReadonly: true }>
    },
    methods?: { [K in keyof M]: M[K] & Function },
}

type User = {
    id: string,
    readonly name?: string
}

function createDomain<T>(o: DomainDefinition<T, any>) {
    return o;
}

export const User = createDomain<User>({
    fields: {
        id: { required: true },
        name: { isReadonly: true },
    },
});
```

If you want to filter out some properties, for example functions, you would have to replace all occurrences of `F` with a filtered `F`. To make it simpler just define an extra type alias:

```
type NonFunctionPropertyNames<T> = { [K in keyof T]: T[K] extends Function ? never : K }[keyof T];
type DomainPropertyHelper<F> = {
  [K in keyof F]: ({} extends { [P in K]: F[K] } ? {} : { required: true }) & {} // Intersect with other properties as necessary
}; 
type DomainDefinition<F, M> = {
    fields?: DomainPropertyHelper<Pick<F, NonFunctionPropertyNames<F>>>,
    methods?: { [K in keyof M]: M[K] & Function },
}
```

Comment: That is a great answer, thanks. I have one additional question though ; your proposal works as is. However, it fails whenever I try to replace `[K in keyof F]` by `[K in NonFunctionPropertyNames<F>]`, with `NonFunctionPropertyNames` defined as on the page https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html. The conditional test is only negative with that change. Would you have any idea why, by luck?

Comment: @Pierre added the code to make it work with filtering as well