# Define equality between types in TypeScript

Tags: typescript, type-level-computation

I just want to define if two types are equals (strict). I suppose equality can be defined using the following type definition:

`type EqualsType<T, U> = T extends U ? true : (U extends T ? true : false)`

Now, suppose we have two type definitions:

```
type User = {
    readonly id: number,
    name: string
}

type UserReadOnly = Readonly<User>
```

In theory, the following assertion should be `false`:

```
type ResultSecondReadOnly = EqualsType<UserReadOnly, User>
```

I cannot understand how conditional type definition works in this case.

Comment: TypeScript uses a structural type system, and the `readonly` modifier does not affect the structure of your object, only its behavior.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52443276/how-to-exclude-getter-only-properties-from-type-in-typescript/52473108#52473108

Comment: While the other question is phrased differently, the underlying issue is the same and the answers are almost exactly what you'd want to see here, so I'm closing this is a duplicate.