# Is it possible to filter out getters using mapped types in typescript?

Tags: typescript, get, getter, mapped-types, conditional-types

I want to define a mapped type that excludes `get` functions from the type that is mapped, however, getters are equivalent to `readonly` properties in their type signature, so the best I could come up with is this:

```js
type IfEquals<X, Y, A, B> =
    (<T>() => T extends X ? 1 : 2) extends
    (<T>() => T extends Y ? 1 : 2) ? A : B;

type WithoutGetters<T> = { 
   [P in keyof T]: IfEquals<{ [Q in P]: T[P] }, { -readonly [Q in P]: T[P] }, P> 
};
```

However, this also excludes regular `readonly` properties, which I *do* want to include.
Is it possible to exclude only the `get` functions and not the rest of the `readonly` properties?

Comment: Guessing `IfEquals` comes from here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52443276/how-to-exclude-getter-only-properties-from-type-in-typescript/52473108#52473108.

Comment: Don't think this is possible, @matt-mccutchen's `IsEqual` is as close to strict equality as it gets and even it can't distinguish between readonly properties and getter properties: https://typescript-play.js.org/#code/C4TwDgpgBAkgZgUQI4FcCGAbAzgHgBoA0UAmkQIJEBCAfFALwBQUzUAFDgCrWsCU9tHKBAAewCADsAJlih4oAfigBGKAC4oAJj4ixUrExbsuvflEE6J0kguVrNfRWTuUA3A3cBjDGiwzfMgG8DZgBzCGAoYV51LGAAJwBLcRCoAKg48JQ48SgAIlyoAF8oBkKGUEhZelhEVExcNIy0SQB7cQwQSJj4pJTCon8iXOJcoYA5XOogA But I have been wrong before :)

Comment: @TitianCernicova-Dragomir you are right, I have added it.

Comment: Getters aren't part of the type; they are treated as implementation details.  The type of `{ get foo() { return "" } }` is `{readonly foo: string}`, so there's no way to distinguish getter-only properties from `readonly` ones at the type level.  Why do you need to distinguish these?  Maybe there's some other way to get what you want (especially if you can annotate the class with the getters in the first place)

Comment: @jcalz I'm trying to create a dynamic type definition of the type of a class after a JSON.stringify and JSON.parse.