# How do you get the type of the object that is cloned from a Class Instance?

Tags: typescript, typescript3.0

assume I have this example class, but in reality it has many more properties

```
class Foo {
  name: string
  dob: number

  constructor(name: string, dob: number) {
    this.name = name;
    this.dob = dob;
  }

  get age() {
     return new Date().getTime() - this.dob
  }
}
```

Now Typescript is smart and when I instantiate the class it will give me all the right properties:

```
var classInstance = new Foo('name', new Date().getTime())

classInstance.name // ok
classInstance.dob // ok
classInstance.age // ok
```

Somewhere in my code the class gets cloned using the Spread Operator, I'm not sure what TS does behind the scene but it is really smart and gives me all the right properties

```
var classJSON = {...classInstance};

classJSON.name // ok
classJSON.dob // ok
classJSON.age // missing
```

[tsplayground](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=3.7.5#code/MYGwhgzhAEBiD29oG8BQ1oDswFsCmAXNBAC4BOAlpgObrQAm8ARkZgK45N5mp3DyZSZNsBLwyACmz4iQqtQA0DZqw5cyAShR0MJABYUIAOml5oAXiy48Abh3R9ho4yYXlTOxgC%20vDNTwk0GD%20ElpoGBFkAWxkmFh4AO7QACJgJHihRv4kACoU%20KHQALQOBsYudD4%20qABuYGTQoJAQAJKCJGCYwGaWmIlwiBIA5KZDSn1JqemZ2XkFGhq8TVBtpJ3dJtaoy63t63jOzNDb4Ct7XQfBeLx1DTsAUgDKAPIAcm7IRl87qx0XXnYTs0nm9NvggVAQa9DkwIRAoUYrtAAPTI6A4QwQeRAA)

This is great, however I sometime need to use the type of `classJSON` .. The only way I can think to extract it is to do this:

```
var classJSON  = {...new Foo('', 0)}
type ClassJSONType = typeof classJSON;
```

Is there a way to extract the type straight out of `Foo` without needing Javascript to instantiate?

Comment: What do you mean by "second type"? Shape of the class instance? If so, it is just `Foo`

Comment: Updated to be more clear.

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52473108/10207459) help?

Comment: I feel like my question can help answer that one, but the tag is ts2.0... a lot has changed since then

Comment: @lonewarrior556 the answer linked above provide the right solution. It still works in ts3.x.

Comment: @hackape the issue being the accepted answer is not the one that has the solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Disclaimer: this post is a mod based on [Matt McCutchen's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52473108/10207459). It's a solid solution, pure TS without any JS runtime effect.

```
type IfEquals<X, Y, T> =
    (<T>() => T extends X ? 1 : 2) extends
  (<T>() => T extends Y ? 1 : 2) ? T : never;

type JSONify<T> = Pick<T, {
  [P in keyof T]: IfEquals<{ [Q in P]: T[P] }, { -readonly [Q in P]: T[P] }, P>
}[keyof T]>;
```

---

Above trick excludes all `readonly` fields. To further exclude methods, use the following:

```
type JSONify<T> = Pick<T, {
  [P in keyof T]: IfEquals<{ [Q in P]: T[P] extends Function ? never : T[P] }, { -readonly [Q in P]: T[P] }, P>
}[keyof T]>;
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ts=3.7.5&ssl=38&ssc=1&pln=41&pc=59#code/C4TwDgpgBAkgZgUQI4FcCGAbAzgHgBoA0UAmkQCoB8UAvAFBQNQAUOlTAlDVWVBAB7AIAOwAmWKHigB+KAEYoALigAmTv0Gis9ZqwocuUHuuFiS0uYpWcZPJUIgA3CACcA3Noa1QkKACkAygDyAHIAlnAgujRQAAqhAMYA1qxEAN7aANoxUKFCUIkQIAD2cIYAukrwyOjYOKlQGQCKOXkxFYZZZVAAvmlQALTOEGgiRUIYIA3NubHtZJ09RDEUtN0ZBcWlZGUU7rQA9PtQKFhoAOYQSrS08RhoWOIAYkVFUOkMQmgAtpdQWMDOXJnbSjABGdhQX1BLmuDHiY3+zhQ8WARWcTE+PyUiKBRDBEKhLk470YwAAFqEsAA6THQahQWnuRhQcmUqlg6Jgpk9WFQC7AKDnCD6EmMIbAFDOPL2ADuUAAImhBBwqfyyKEfvp+iyKdSwdpuqtrg40M4oLd7lgYEJ-mghPE6QyIHLnkUmAByWnuoiyhVK4XsVUQYDqzXsdjXbzQADCdweARC0QTYQiOFdKxucatNuAdodNO+EEzluttvtEHZRVBUGLD1LufLVKFxtN5qzyaUsctyeiqW6gvEdpAewt8aCwQLP1rWGTldB09nQqgh14fFuKBEEBEtCAA)

Comment: The question probably should be closed as duplicated, but the bounty prevent the action, so I post this one.

Comment: Please be aware that this solution cannot exclude inherited methods and excludes `readonly` fields

Comment: @Shlang Original answer does excludes `readonly` fields, as to methods, see my edit.

Comment: Thank you, but it still has some limitations. Please check this [playground](https://stackblitz.com/edit/typescript-nw5qyh)

Comment: @Shlang Now I get your point. Yeah you're right about this solution is not covering every aspect. The type system is simply blind to object's own property.

Comment: While this is good, it does not work when there is something readonly in the constructor which is assignable on creation. So getters and readonly properties are treated the same.

Answer (score 3):

If all you're trying to avoid is initialising Foo, you can do something like this:

```js
var funRetClassJSON = () => ({ ...Foo.prototype });
type TypeOfClassJSON = ReturnType<typeof funRetClassJSON>;
```

or

```js
var nullClassJSON = false as any ? null : ({ ...Foo.prototype });
type AltTypeOfClassJSON = NonNullable<typeof nullClassJSON>;
```

Of course, both these examples still incur some runtime penalty, as some JS is still generated.

Comment: I like this alot, although not pure TS, it does avoid initializing Foo which in reality had a complex constructor.

Answer (score 2):

It is not possible at the moment because TS type system does not allow tracking non-own properties.
There is a [proposal](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/10727) for exactly what you want. [This comment](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/pull/21316#issuecomment-359574388) also describes possible ways to express Spread operator without stripping non-own properties.