# Ensure an interface is in par with a union type?

Tags: typescript

Given this union type:

```ts
type Type = 'one' | 'two' | 'three'
```

How can I type the following object to ensure that it a) covers every possible value of `Type`; and b) allows me to have per-type function signatures?

```ts
const factories = {
    one(a: string) { return /* whatever */ },
    two(a: number, b: number) { return /* whatever */ },
    three() { return /* whatever */ }
}

function getFactory<T extends keyof typeof factories>(type: T): typeof factories[T] {
    return factories[type]
}
```

If I don't type the object, like above, I have full type checking but not exhaustivity - I can easily forget or misspell a member. In my real-life use case, `Type` is 30+ possibilities and growing so this really matters.

If I use a `Record`, such as `const factories: Record<Type, any>` or `const factories: Record<Type, Function>`, it have exhaustivity but I loose type checking of the function signatures.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Aplet123's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65174344/2887218) is correct; I just wanted to follow up with a version that does not result in any changes to the emitted JavaScript code.  Personally, I don't think that an extra line or two of JavaScript is a big deal, but if you'd like to completely restrict the effects of the type checking to the static type system, you could do it this way:

```
type ExhaustiveFactories<T extends Record<Type, any> =
  typeof factories> = void;
```

That line will be completely erased when the JavaScript is emitted.  If it  compiles, it's because `factories` has a property for every element of `Type`; otherwise, you'll get an error telling you which property or properties of `Type` are missing in `factories`, such as:

```
type Type = 'one' | 'two' | 'three';

const factories = {
  one(a: string) { return /* whatever */ },
  two(a: number, b: number) { return /* whatever */ },
}

type ExhaustiveFactories<T extends Record<Type, any> =
  typeof factories> = void; // error!
//~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ <-- Property "three" is missing
```

or:

```
const factories = {
  one(a: string) { return /* whatever */ },
  two(a: number, b: number) { return /* whatever */ },
  thwee() { return /* whatever */ },
}

type ExhaustiveFactories<T extends Record<Type, any> =
  typeof factories> = void; // error!
//~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ <-- Property "three" is missing
```

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#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-SbTOZQRbLVZwSAbLaXHzcyDohUiS5Qa63WhmNxOSgCACEPlMpgAfqWy+WK8WoCMALQ1qAABVzkEooCgACJ8jR21BWVBgqz2RpGJ7qbT6YyoCy2ZAADaziAzHVelpRxAoWSivxb8V0RjStgcYlnERKyQq1XyJQarVFR3lZ0ZGrZeoX83Xy1xSLRKCfpx3kpkgfSon2Nd033IAgaDkAC9WAw1XRfU1PQTaAfW4bpgF6CAvhJUZxmDQFQ3DARI3WKBNh2PY3yhY5jzhVN0zuLMJkoXNKALaQi0rHiy2rOtG2bJw207Xcez7Ac2Q5dQR0YIA)

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for, thank you! I just replaced `any` with `Function` because I really want all entries to be, well... functions. Also, I must point out, that this does not prevent me from adding properties that don't exist on `Type` - but *this* is not a big deal ;)

Answer (score 2):

If you just want typescript to throw an error when it's missing a key, then just put a cast after the declaration:

```
const factories = {
    one(a: string) { return /* whatever */ },
    two(a: number, b: number) { return /* whatever */ },
    three() { return /* whatever */ }
};

factories as Record<Type, any>;
```

If you change `three` to `foo`, then the cast will error saying that there are incompatible error types. You could alternatively use a function that forces typescript to narrow the key types down to `Type`:

```
type Type = 'one' | 'two' | 'three';

function forceTypeKey<T>(obj: Record<Type, any> & T): T {
    return obj;
}

const factories = forceTypeKey({
    one(a: string) { return /* whatever */ },
    two(a: number, b: number) { return /* whatever */ },
    three() { return /* whatever */ }
});
```

Comment: Smart. I would prefer a solution that does not imply extra code generation, but if I don't get one within the next few days, I'll accept your answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

```
type Type = "one" | "two" | "three";

type Factories = {
  [K in Type]: typeof factories[K];
};

// It will become circular so you can't assign here
const factories = {
  one(a: string) {
    return; /* whatever */
  },
  two(a: number, b: number) {
    return; /* whatever */
  },
  three() {
    return; /* whatever */
  }
};

// But you will get an error due to lack of support
// for index type if your const factories is missing
// a key from type 
function getFactory<T extends Type>(type: T): Factories[T] {
  return factories[type];
}

const f = getFactory("one"); // will be (a: string) => void
```

Comment: No. This is the same as using a `Record`, as I stated in my question. With this solution, I loose type checking on the different factories, ie. `getFactory()` always return `(...args: any[]) => any`.

Comment: Updated. Hope this helps you.

Comment: Much, much better, and working as asked - thanks. However, I still prefer @jcalz's answer as Intellisense then tells me which property key is missing.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an addition to [jcalz's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65175117/14725934), that also checks for excess properties (see your [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65174291/ensure-an-interface-is-in-par-with-a-union-type#comment115223399_65175117)):

```
type AssertAssignable<Expected, Actual extends Expected> = Actual

type AssertFactories =
  AssertAssignable<Record<Type, any>, typeof factories> &
  AssertAssignable<typeof factories, Record<Type, any>>
```

```
// Example
const factories = {
  one(a: string) { return ... },
  two(a: number, b: number) { return ... },
  three: "foo",
  four: 42  // <-- error
}
```

A more [concise magic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52443276/how-to-exclude-getter-only-properties-from-type-in-typescript/52473108#52473108) alternative:

```
type AssertFactories2<U extends (
  (<T>() => T extends typeof factories ? 1 : 2) extends
  (<T>() => T extends {[P in Type]: typeof factories[P] } ? 1 : 2) ? typeof factories : 
  "Sorry, excess or missing property in typeof factories"
  )
  = typeof factories> = U
```

This complex looking conditional type just makes sure, `typeof factories` is *identical* to `{[P in Type]: typeof factories[P] }`.

You can take a look at the [playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAKu0F4oHID2A7CyoB8XAHdVs9lgALAJwiwG4AoegYwwGdgoAzAQyeFUoBLCKyhIA3vShQMEABTcAXFHZD0AcwCUUcVGrAArpXRQA9ACooBct2AQAbhEpRzpqAF8ANFKiFUC5XQDAFsAIydPKFDAkPDKbV19IxMLKxs7R2dXD29pCmoIZQAiTlRUItyzN1KjZQAWACZpUzcAWgA%20KAN0FmDgiHQOfhVBYIMAG1toAGtBdAATGU4oCAAPJhFRMEpUSEpQKCZyCCZp%20ndGUEgoAEFWVidgO9ZBdXRuUPGIAB4AUVXIHwIPNIjc%20AZuOMVqs7AtRP9AXZ5p0kGDDJDLvBbvdHgAxXj8IQiMQ%20Z6PZ6vd6fH4AJROAnm3zgkEi3HQIHakSuEFQyx4fAEwlYnQAZKScfsKW8Pl9vtzeVwCYKRJE6SxKIzmRBWez2u1Mdcyft8QKiawGt8AKrQ2HzURyHxyJntOTaBCdGA2gZ23zwBX8wlCqAAfigAEYoMoGto1rbWI7na6xB6vXCdABtAAKUDmsHgAF1lPK%20UqzVn8x4Q%20HI1Bo1Xi4rTUHlD4igBlASUECRNYbe4yZzBQT3ObqKDbXaPEA5kwNgPK1hFHyaHxIOeloUoqCWxhAA).