# Making a Mapped Type in TypeScript where readonly keys can be set to a specific value

Tags: typescript, readonly, mapped-types

I'd like to create a generic mapped type in TypeScript with the following concepts:

1. Allows any writable key from the base type to be set to a value (same type as in the base type) or a pre-defined flag
2. Allows readonly keys to be set ONLY to the pre-defined flag.

Here is a non-working example of the concept:

```ts
type KindOfMutable1<T> = {
    -readonly[P in keyof T]?: "FLAG";
} | {  // THIS DOES NOT WORK
    [P in keyof T]?: T[P] | "FLAG"
};

interface thingy {
    x: number;
    readonly v: number;
}
const thing1: KindOfMutable1<thingy> = {x: 1};
thing1.v = "FLAG";
//     ^ ERROR HERE: Cannot assign to 'v' because it is a read-only property
```

Another way to think about my desired solution would look something like this:

```ts
// pseudo code of a concept:
type KindOfMutable2<T> = {
    [P in keyof T]?: /* is T[P] readonly */ ? "FLAG" : T[P] | "FLAG"
};
```

Is there any way to do this?

Comment: Does [this approach](https://tsplay.dev/mbBAEm) meet your needs?  If so I could write up an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: @jcalz That looks like it would meet my needs.  Please do write it up in an answer.  Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Detecting [`readonly` properties](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#readonly-properties) vs mutable properties is tricky, because object types that differ only in their "read-onliness" are considered mutually assignable.  A variable of type `{a: string}` will accept a value of type `{readonly a: string}` and vice versa.  See [microsoft/TypeScript#13347](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/13347) for more information.

It *is* possible, but only by using a technique shown in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52473108/2887218) where we get the compiler to tell us whether it considers two types "*identical*" as opposed to just mutually assignable:

```
type IfEquals<X, Y, A = X, B = never> =
    (<T>() => T extends X ? 1 : 2) extends
    (<T>() => T extends Y ? 1 : 2) ? A : B;

type MutableProps<T> = {
    [P in keyof T]-?: IfEquals<
      { [Q in P]: T[P] }, { -readonly [Q in P]: T[P] }, P>
}[keyof T];
```

The `MutableProps<T>` type gives you the non-`readonly` keys of `T`, by comparing whether an explicitly non-`readonly` version of the property is "*identical*" to the original version:

```
type MutablePropsOfThingy = MutableProps<Thingy>;
// type MutablePropsOfThingy = "x"
```

And so you can write `KindOfMutable<T>` specifically in terms of `MutableProps<T>`:

```
type KindOfMutable<T> = {
    -readonly [P in keyof T]?: "FLAG" | (P extends MutableProps<T> ? T[P] : never)
}
```

Resulting in:

```
type KindOfMutableThingy = KindOfMutable<Thingy>;
/* type KindOfMutable1Thingy = {
    x?: number | "FLAG" | undefined;
    v?: "FLAG" | undefined;
} */
```

which works how you want:

```
const thing1: KindOfMutable<Thingy> = { x: 1 }; // okay
thing1.v = "FLAG"; // okay
```

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=28&ssc=1&pln=30&pc=1#code/C4TwDgpgBAkgZgUQI4FcCGAbAzgHgBoA0UAmkQIJQC8UhUAQlVAHYQBuEATgHxUCwAUAEgAFDgAqXYQEoqPMVAgAPYBCYATLDSgB+KAEYoALigAmGUpXqsAkeMkzKchctUaSO-UdMzdFY3QBuAQFQSCgAWRRgNAAjDAgABQ4AezBcCUYAbxsAbQSoAEsmKABrCBBkuCgxAF0AWm1jeGR0bBxMqByARULihJrjMTyaqABfIg66jgg0NWSmDBBOnqKofsHhsaIErgFRnLKKqtqg-mD+UOgAaSK1AHk4SOi4iDssmymZuYWlvN7S8qVao1RpQABEADEADJkADiYKgAB8oMJ8hZXJonrF4klUukeLohv0vCx2BwpHtzkUVBw4GgAMbQMQACyKAHMltkhIpjEwUABbGKcU6CaazeaLKCsXkCoUcU6jc6XCJRbGJFJpB4s9lLahYl64tLiVlMDlcU4AegtUGV+pxGqwWpNHMYYMUYKV4Gutwedog2tNuqgN3UvtVL2NOvNAgtACobV7gz7HuH4noAy7qFzBIpQXzBZwkeDoXCEciUOoIHAihA1CLWKDITD4UWK2oqzW63soLGLed6fMsMAbc69MYQ-cU894pHAzws1AeZ5RgEoFaoMkSmgQCFRwA6Viukvw1frzfbgRQIA)

Comment: That is tricky, but it’s clever and it works. Thanks!