# Cannot remove optional when mapping type with exclude

Tags: typescript

I want to remove the optional of fields of type like:

```js
type Optinal = {
  a?: string;
  b?: number;
}

type Mapped1 = { [K in keyof Optinal]-?: Optinal[K] }
/*
type Mapped1 = {
    a: string;
    b: number;
}
*/
```

Which was fine as above. However, while I want to also exclude some fields from the mapping like:

```js
type Mapped2 = { [K in Exclude<keyof Optinal, 'b'>]-?: Optinal[K] }
/*
type Mapped2 = {
    a: string | undefined;
}
*/
```

Then the field `a` of `Mapped2` became `string | undefined`.

Why the `-?` doesn't work with `Exclude`?

Comment: Yes the 'Required' works but I still want to know why '-?' doesn't work.

Comment: Doesn't answer your question but [Omit](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#omittype-keys) and [Required](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#requiredtype) are much easier... `type Mapped2 = Required<Omit<Optinal, 'b'>>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The behaviour you see is a mix of:

- typescript treating `keyof` types in a special way (which gets discarded by `Exclude`)
- `{ a?: string }` being equivalent to `{ a?: string | undefined }` (a behavior that can be turned off with `exactOptionalPropertyTypes`)

A possible solution is to use an `as` clause:

```
type Mapped3 = { [K in keyof Optinal as Exclude<K, 'b'>]-?: Optinal[K] }
```

Comment: 'typescript treating keyof types in a special way' do you have any link that points this information?

Comment: See for example "keys in mapped object types (K) are actually not only types, but types with "requiredness" and "readonlyness" attached;" https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50829805/get-keyof-non-optional-property-names-in-typescript/50830054#50830054

Comment: The "special way" is that makes the type *homomorphic* as discussed in https://stackoverflow.com/q/59790508/2887218.