Why doesn't TypeScript throw an error with T[P] in a mapped type when T is a union of strings and not an object?
T is a generic type constrained to a union of strings ('title' | 'completed'). My goal was to understand how TypeScript handles T[P] in a mapped type, given that T is a union of string literals and not an actual object with properties:
type B<T extends 'title' | 'completed'> = { [P in keyof T]: T[P] }; 
Intuitively, I would expect an error here because T isn't an object, so T[P] shouldn’t be valid.
Thanks !

If T is a string-type, or string-compatible type, then keyof T will be keyof String which would be 'length' (which is the only property on String.prototype.

Have you seen this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50829805/get-keyof-non-optional-property-names-in-typescript

It's a homomorphic mapped type, and therefore just returns its input when the input is a primitive. See the linked q/a for more information. So you're not really iterating over keyof 'title' if you evaluate B<'title'>. Of course it is possible to write keyof string because string extends String, where String is the wrapper object. So if you were to do that it still wouldn't be an error.
