# Excluding readonly fields in `keyof T` operator

Tags: angular, typescript, ngrx

I am writing an angular application where one of my components subscribes to lots of values from a ngrx store. My `ngOnInit` function looks like:

```
this.store.pipe(select(searchResults), takeUntil(this.destroyed$))
  .subscribe(results => this.searchResults = results);
this.store.pipe(select(searchError), takeUntil(this.destroyed$))
  .subscribe(error => this.searchError = error);
// Lots of similar statements below
```

I think this is overly verbose. It also makes it difficult to grasp at a glance which fields get their values from the store. My intuition says it should be possible to write this in a more concise way, like in the example below:

```
this.syncField(searchResults, 'searchResults');
this.syncField(searchError, 'searchError');
// Lots of similar statements below
```

This approach relies on a `syncField` method, which I have been unable to write. I tried the following:

```
syncField<T>(selector: MemoizedSelector<object, T>, field: keyof MyComponent) {
    this.store.pipe(select(selector), takeUntil(this.destroyed$)).subscribe(value => {
        this[field] = value;
    });
}
```

However, the component has some read-only fields, which causes the assignment (`this[field] = value`) to fail with the message: `Cannot assign to [readonly field name] because it is a constant or a read-only property.`.

This gives raise to the questions:

1. Is it possible to use `keyof T` in such a way that it filters out read-only properties?
2. If this is impossible, is there another way we could write the `syncField` method?
3. Alternatively, is there a best practice to make subscribing to lots of observables less verbose?

Comment: Thanks for the link, though I would suggest [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49579094/typescript-conditional-types-filter-out-readonly-properties-pick-only-requir) one as a duplicate instead

Comment: Sure, jcalz is in the process of adding the new technique to question 49579094 too.

Comment: @MattMcCutchen sorry my bad forgot about your workaround to filter out readonly props.