# is there a way to turn an optional property like { x?: number } to required (undefinable) `{ x: undefined | number }` via map types in typescript?

Tags: typescript

I have something like `{ y: string; x?: number }`, i need to get `{ y: string; x: undefined | number }`. Is there a way to turn the first one into the second one via map types in typescript?

Answer (score 3):

You can get the type you want using mapped types. You can get the optional and required keys from a type as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49579094/typescript-conditional-types-filter-out-readonly-properties-pick-only-requir/49579497#49579497)

```
type OptionalKeys<T> = { [K in keyof T]-?:
  ({} extends { [P in K]: T[K] } ? K : never)
}[keyof T]

type RequiredKeys<T> = { [K in keyof T]-?:
  ({} extends { [P in K]: T[K] } ? never : K)
}[keyof T]

type Id<T> = { [P in keyof T]: T[P]}
type OptionalToUndefined<T> = Id<{
  [K in OptionalKeys<T>]-?: T[K] | undefined  
} & { 
  [K in RequiredKeys<T>]-?: T[K] 
}>
//  { y: number | undefined; x: boolean; }
type Foo = OptionalToUndefined<{ x: boolean; y?: number }>
```

Comment: can you explain what this does: {} extends { [P in K]: T[K] }

Comment: @AlekseyBykov I included a link to the original source of the types jcalz explains it  there and you should read it and upvote him, but the idea is that : `{}` extends `{a?: string}`, but `{}` does not extend `{a: string}` or even `{a: string | undefined}`

Comment: In other words, `{} extends { [P in K]: T[K] }` type condition is true if empty object is compatible with a type which has its properties in `K`, meaning that all these properties are optional. And the outer mapped type `{[K in keyof T] ...}` makes `K` go over properties from `keyof T` one by one, allowing the condition to select only optional ones (or required in the inverted case).

Comment: you gave me an idea, here is my solution:

`type EachNonOptional<T> = { [K in keyof T]-?: T[K]; }`

`type EachUndefinedOrNever<T> = { [K in keyof T]: undefined extends T[K] ? undefined : never };`

`type EachOptionalAsUndefined<T> = { [K in keyof T]: EachNonOptional<T>[K] | EachUndefinedOrNever<T>[K] };`

Comment: @AlekseyBykov not exactly the same. In your question the optionality is removed from the resulting type. The property can be `undefined` but it has to be present. The version in the comment keeps the property as optional.

Comment: here i fixed it: 
`type EachNonOptional<T> = { [K in keyof T]-?: T[K]; }
type EachUndefinedOrNever<T> = { [K in keyof T]: undefined extends T[K] ? undefined : never };
type EachOptionalAsUndefined<T> = { [K in keyof EachNonOptional<T>]: EachNonOptional<T>[K] | EachUndefinedOrNever<T>[K] };`

Comment: jeez, it's even simplier than that:
```type EachNonOptional<T> = { [K in keyof T]-?: T[K]; }
type EachOptionalAsUndefined<T> = { [K in keyof EachNonOptional<T>]:T[K] };
```

Answer (score 1):

<strike>I ended up using this:</strike>

```
type EachNonOptional<T> = { [K in keyof T]-?: T[K]; }
type EachUndefinedOrNever<T> = { [K in keyof T]: undefined extends T[K] ? undefined : never };
type EachOptionalAsUndefined<T> = { [K in keyof EachNonOptional<T>]: EachNonOptional<T>[K] | EachUndefinedOrNever<T>[K] };
declare const x: EachOptionalAsUndefined<{ x?: number; y: string}>; // {x : number | undefined; x: string; }
```

or EVEN SIMPLIER:

```
type EachNonOptional<T> = { [K in keyof T]-?: T[K]; }
type EachOptionalAsUndefined<T> = { [K in keyof EachNonOptional<T>]: T[K] };
```