# How to get a string union of the required keys of a type

Tags: typescript

I would like to build a string union of all the required keys of a type. 
Example:

```js
interface IPerson {
    readonly name: string;
    age?: number;
    weight: number;
}

RequiredKeys<IPerson>  // a type returning "name" | "weight"
ReadonlyKeys<IPerson>  // a type returning "name"
```

I can't figure out how to filter out optional (or readonly) keys

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TypeScript doesn't have a built in method yet to extract optionals.

```
interface IPerson {
  readonly name: string;
  age?: number;
  weight: number;
}

// First get the optional keys
type Optional<T> = {
  [K in keyof T]-?: ({} extends { [P in K]: T[K] } ? K : never)
}[keyof T];

// Use the pick to select them from the rest of the interface
const optionalPerson: Pick<IPerson, Optional<IPerson>> = {
  age: 2
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @ali-habibzadeh

```js
type RequiredKeys<T> = {
  [K in keyof T]-?: ({} extends { [P in K]: T[K] } ? never : K)
}[keyof T];

type OptionalKeys<T> = {
  [K in keyof T]-?: ({} extends { [P in K]: T[K] } ? K : never)
}[keyof T];
```

To get the readonly/writable keys you can use: [Details](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49579497/861358)

```js
type IfEquals<X, Y, A=X, B=never> =
  (<T>() => T extends X ? 1 : 2) extends
  (<T>() => T extends Y ? 1 : 2) ? A : B;

type WritableKeys<T> = {
  [P in keyof T]-?: IfEquals<{ [Q in P]: T[P] }, { -readonly [Q in P]: T[P] }, P>
}[keyof T];

type ReadonlyKeys<T> = {
  [P in keyof T]-?: IfEquals<{ [Q in P]: T[P] }, { -readonly [Q in P]: T[P] }, never, P>
}[keyof T];
```