# TypeScript: Elegant way to provide optional parameters?

Tags: typescript, default-parameters

Background: I am working on a game and I want the physics engine to be exchangeable, so each engine implementation has to be wrapped into a common interface. For instance, each engine has to implement the following function:

```js
createCircle(position, radius = 1)
```

but let's generalize and go with frobnicate which needs two required parameters and two optional parameters.

Here would be my ideal which is not possible in TypeScript:

```js
interface FrobCfg {
    reqA: number
    reqB: number
    optC?: number = 13
    optD?: number = 37
}
type FrobnicateFn = (cfg: FrobCfg) => void
```

and then an engine implements:

```js
let frobnicate:FrobnicateFn = function(cfg: FrobCfg) {
    console.log(cfg.reqA, cfg.reqB, cfg.optC, cfg.optD)
}
frobnicate({reqA:1, reqB:2, optC:3})
```

Note that the default values are actually already known and should be consistent across all engines. Many approaches do not consider this.

---

Edit2: Here is the version I am now going with:

```js
// Interface
//----------
interface FrobCfg{
    reqA:number
    reqB:number
    optC?:number
    optD?:number
}
const frobDefaults:Optionals<FrobCfg> = {
    optC:13,
    optD:37
}
type Frobnicator = (cfg: FrobCfg) => void

// Implementation
//---------------
const frobnicate:Frobnicator = (cfg: FrobCfg) => {
    const {reqA, reqB, optC, optD}:Required<FrobCfg> =
        {...frobDefaults, ...cfg}

    console.log(reqA, reqB, optC, optD)
}

// Call
//-----
frobnicate({reqA:1, reqB:2, optC:3})


// Generics Utilities
// https://stackoverflow.com/a/49579497/3825996

type IfEquals<X, Y, A=X, B=never> =
  (<T>() => T extends X ? 1 : 2) extends
  (<T>() => T extends Y ? 1 : 2) ? A : B;

type RequiredKeys<T> = { [K in keyof T]-?:
  ({} extends { [P in K]: T[K] } ? never : K)
}[keyof T]

type OptionalKeys<T> = { [K in keyof T]-?:
  ({} extends { [P in K]: T[K] } ? K : never)
}[keyof T]

type Optionals<T> = Required<Pick<T, OptionalKeys<T>>>
```

[TypeScript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/PTAEEkDsBcFMCcBmBDAxrAUCAtLv%20MBLGBFdUAMXgHsAjAYUQHMBvDUD0eWARwEEAXJACuAW1oJ2nbjwBCQsRPhSO1AA7R6AfgXjJnUOugARHSL3KAvhlTVIAZ2ihENWsdgphAG2j2BAeQ1CO2QvewAeKjpGJgA%20UABeUDYDI3oBAEYAZgAaFUMNYwEsgHYMa2gATzVYSldIQlRkaGp4RNAAClRmATro5gBKRPiAN2pCABMMLDBwUTUvWFFYGGbgyBn8Le2bO0dnesbm2AEo2gamlrakrp6%20hkHh5PzbBycWGT4crl5Zb7T-oVLAIAEq8YSEbgTSKuGLxBL5AwsAB0qJcdHcnh89m%20qOR3SY1gMLz21EWyK81CYHU%203xkfwKmkBJgG5WmIFA9FCXk2BHR5yOcA6H14ggydN%20AgATMz0llLKz2WAAOIrBCNeygACq0EIXkIutg9hmoAAFtBoGo-CBHGgANbUEakSkAd3x1FEwGQwAALABOACsJT9-pKwCyAA4pQG-X6AGzTKo1CCIACiPGEoQiAA1vgBNb58BK50CyBKQWBO%20DwqQdcIAFViHSGCXi9dAsAAHnBIBNNdnQFpQBlQL0pUMuz2%207WG02W22O92Vn3QHnB8PR6Bx%20u%20JvZABuRPVWpgjOQ2ATADSsEqEUb7RYoAA2pfQMRQHab9REKB6wBdbAdFrFhLEXKdNUfJ8AAU30gUBLz-Xp6xfP9QFAocKyrTdL1ZSwn0-Spv1-P8j2TQJdRCLxr1vWcH2fV93wIoj-0AgRgNAydlwg58YPfBCkJQtD11fXpMIQXD8K-H9-1I2pyPWLNaKSU8IShcIoMaO0G2%20eTKOou9YkMoA)

---

Here is everything I've tried in order to approximate the original ideal. The function type definition has been omitted for brevity.

```js
// 0) the obvious way:
//--------------------
function frobnicate0(reqA: number, reqB: number, optC: number = 13, optD: number = 37) {
    console.log(reqA, reqB, optC, optD)
}
frobnicate0(1, 2, 3)
// + super short
// - parameters are not named in call
// - order matters
// - optional parameters cannot be skipped
// - consistency of default values not enforced across implementations


// 1) the common way:
//-------------------
interface Frob1Cfg {
    reqA: number
    reqB: number
    optC?: number
    optD?: number
}
function frobnicate1(cfg: Frob1Cfg) {
    let optC = cfg.optC || 13
    let optD = cfg.optD || 37
    console.log(cfg.reqA, cfg.reqB, optC, optD)
}
frobnicate1({reqA:1, reqB:2, optC:0})
// + pretty short
// - || does not really convey intent to beginners
// - consistency of default values not enforced across implementations
// - fails unacceptably on falsy arguments!!!


// 2) the elaborate way:
//----------------------
interface Frob2Cfg {
    reqA: number
    reqB: number
    optC?: number
    optD?: number
}
function frobnicate2(cfg: Frob2Cfg) {
    let optC = typeof(cfg.optC) !== "undefined"? cfg.optC : 13
    let optD = typeof(cfg.optD) !== "undefined"? cfg.optD : 37
    console.log(cfg.reqA, cfg.reqB, optC, optD)
}
frobnicate2({reqA:1, reqB:2, optC:0})
// + rock-solid
// - very elaborate and un-DRY-esque
// - if multiple functions want a Frob2Cfg, it's extra repeating
// - consistency of default values not enforced across implementations


// 3) another idea:
//-----------------
class Frob3Cfg{
    reqA: number
    reqB: number
    optC: number = 13
    optD: number = 37
    constructor(cfg: Pick<Frob3Cfg, 'reqA' | 'reqB'> & Partial<Frob3Cfg>){
        Object.assign(this, cfg)
    }
}
function frobnicate3(cfg: Frob3Cfg){
    console.log(cfg.reqA, cfg.reqB, cfg.optC, cfg.optD)
}
frobnicate3(new Frob3Cfg({reqA:1, reqB:2, optC:0}))
// - TypeScript complains that reqA and reqB are not assigned
// - the cfg type in the constructor is somewhat complicated
// + if all parameters are optional it's ok
// - call is elaborate
// + the function can be sure it gets a full cfg which looks very clean
// + and scales very well if more functions require a Frob3Cfg
// + the cfg object can be reused and is completed with defaults
//   only once and not with every function call
// - ts tooltip when writing a call is unhelpful


// 4) yet another one:
//--------------------
interface Frob4Cfg{
    reqA: number
    reqB: number
    optC?: number
    optD?: number
}
function fillFrob4Cfg(cfg:Frob4Cfg):Required<Frob4Cfg>{
    return Object.assign({}, {optC:13, optD:37}, cfg)
}
function frobnicate4(cfg:Frob4Cfg){
    let fullcfg = fillFrob4Cfg(cfg)
    console.log(fullcfg.reqA, fullcfg.reqB, fullcfg.optC, fullcfg.optD)
}
frobnicate4({reqA:1, reqB:2, optC:3})
// + short function definition, short call
// - extra function necessary
// - defaults are copied and overwritten
// - default values somewhat hidden


// 5) awesome ES6 way I found after some googling:
//------------------------------------------------
interface Frob5Cfg{
    reqA: number
    reqB: number
    optC?: number
    optD?: number
}
function frobnicate5({reqA, reqB, optC=13, optD=37}:Frob5Cfg){
    console.log(reqA, reqB, optC, optD)
}
frobnicate5({reqA:1, reqB:2, optC:3})
// - nothing forces the implementer of frobnicate to consider optC and optD
// - consistency of default values not enforced across implementations


// 6) next try:
//-------------
type Optional<T, K extends keyof T> = Omit<T, K> & Partial<Pick<T, K>>
type OptionalExcept<T, K extends keyof T> = Pick<T, K> & Partial<Omit<T, K>>
type AllOptional<T> = Partial<T> // for consistency

class Frob6Cfg{
    reqA:number
    reqB:number
    optC:number
    optD:number
    constructor({reqA, reqB, optC = 13, optD = 37}:Optional<Frob6Cfg, 'optC' | 'optD'>){
        this.reqA = reqA
        this.reqB = reqB
        this.optC = optC
        this.optD = optD
    }
}
function frobnicate6(cfg: Frob6Cfg){
    console.log(cfg.reqA, cfg.reqB, cfg.optC, cfg.optD)
}
frobnicate6(new Frob6Cfg({reqA:1, reqB:2, optC:0}))
// - lot of repetition
// - function call elaborate
// + solves everything else


// 7) again with factory:
//-----------------------

// (already defined above)
// type Optional<T, K extends keyof T> = Omit<T, K> & Partial<Pick<T, K>>
// type OptionalExcept<T, K extends keyof T> = Pick<T, K> & Partial<Omit<T, K>>
// type AllOptional<T> = Partial<T> // for consistency

interface Frob7Cfg{
    reqA:number
    reqB:number
    optC:number
    optD:number
}
function defaultFrob7({
    reqA,
    reqB,
    optC = 13,
    optD = 37
}:Optional<Frob7Cfg, 'optC' | 'optD'>):Frob7Cfg{
    return arguments[0]
}
function frobnicate7(cfg: Frob7Cfg){
    console.log(cfg.reqA, cfg.reqB, cfg.optC, cfg.optD)
}
frobnicate7(defaultFrob7({reqA:1, reqB:2, optC:3}))
// - still somewhat elaborate
// - typescript thinks the arguments of defaultFrob7 are not used

// EDIT:

// 8) adapted suggestion by ritaj:
//--------------------------------
interface Frob8Cfg{
    reqA:number
    reqB:number
    optC?:number
    optD?:number
}
const frob8defaults:Optionals<Frob8Cfg> = {
    optC:13,
    optD:37
}
function frob8defaultizer(impl:(fullCfg:Required<Frob8Cfg>) => void){
    return function(halfCfg:Frob8Cfg){
        const filledCfg:Required<Frob8Cfg> = {...frob8defaults, ...halfCfg}
        return impl(filledCfg)
    }
}
const frobnicate8 = frob8defaultizer((cfg: Required<Frob8Cfg>)=>{
    console.log(cfg.reqA, cfg.reqB, cfg.optC, cfg.optD)
})
// - I find the function builder super confusing


// 9) solution inspired by ritaj and this
// https://stackoverflow.com/a/49579497/3825996
//---------------------------------------------
interface Frob9Cfg{
    reqA:number
    reqB:number
    optC?:number
    optD?:number
}
let frob9defaults:Optionals<Frob9Cfg> = {optC:13, optD:37}

function frobnicate9(cfg: Frob9Cfg){
    let fullCfg:Required<Frob9Cfg> = {...frob9defaults, ...cfg}
}
frobnicate9({reqA:1, reqB:2, optC:3})
// -+ defaults not enforced but easily kept consistent


// credits to
// https://stackoverflow.com/a/49579497/3825996
type IfEquals<X, Y, A=X, B=never> =
  (<T>() => T extends X ? 1 : 2) extends
  (<T>() => T extends Y ? 1 : 2) ? A : B;

type RequiredKeys<T> = { [K in keyof T]-?:
  ({} extends { [P in K]: T[K] } ? never : K)
}[keyof T]

type OptionalKeys<T> = { [K in keyof T]-?:
  ({} extends { [P in K]: T[K] } ? K : never)
}[keyof T]

type Requireds<T> = Pick<T, RequiredKeys<T>>
type Optionals<T> = Required<Pick<T, OptionalKeys<T>>>
```

<s>All of these approaches have some shortcomings.</s>
I am now pretty satisfied with the latest approach. But still open for suggestions!
Is there any ultimately beautiful way I have not considered? [TypeScript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#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-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-k20AHzgAAZOAjNTLw9zs1UqMyoL0Dowq4AAPLoAAVkgPApKQJLYBkHDSIgoLJT6RoVFakmAzJDq1EgHgM2tGByxkitU-EsV5glhY5KbpapX7DmByJVaVLbToO-uxBO+gLvSPlShNnkqVtuWpXduV4wACrkH0ADKRJ-GsbIUqQuxEIgEgtooXXbPkBJyDOay6wQ+v7g1QHwARybwLnKC7F3rLU4ItObpDRAJLMxAIFXJeJDlHcVZNBIHI80yzC8SzGncDxbbtaDfEC847HtbUdUgoxdCyAhW9J4j8F8PSN1t4AZHMiw36vPfT2ICDgOkqBvhEGXIIRcyQ3iX1rt0fY04QGQmIK1XeU0hjzVvktAweBsCN1IDHF2kDr49wwJrHgrwH4oDkIQD63UT4xFQL9SQ2xiBbT-teGagFhIcDgnEUUbxtgYiYYgTEcCb42jvvOa4cAK6oCSLNEgyB+DEEEFtXYsocH7F3uBDgyBEiWHYIcBk7QAAssByDxjeODfocQkCw3hpRQU1JtB0RjoYtGXF2J40NDjFOWNPEEz1GJUmJoBIWkNJbURdpQKJAYi4mUDNonMWgJQfqChMFyE2DLDAMSMiCyVgOPAgh+Bq2IXAHWesDbxzKHoMIJVPDFEoCESpJZQ4LWtllWskhDFxKqFkt2Cp-Sf0SD3VwQUDjxNicmUo0UAKe3itIPRgyfZKD0PMlKRhlkIgWSmQM6yDheRDplWSdtOkJ2UIVFOxVCYeG7JAkcQw1gtOklZUQgM9C3OGK8A41wDpHRwQ8zk+48QkimOQa4rDESLEbrESw2AqHbFQCAxRW1wSgoejNO8z0J50KQNPKuCB6qnA4MDCAABWWApAEGTxQAAUTzgANjIuAAAkgIfA1DSCsHmN0LFr9pEZHnudGxtihXCv5PY4UhJ6JVGJa4rxicfFuNbPKwJNhgmcUCaJeVYTFoIUOU6Yl8ckotjSoGZwtSEzOAaZQBi0qfRKxirmWZhqyzpQTM03Vkh9UnKTka1OHZ6nXMah8PF50WVvmnNfMkc1-qWOhG0nK8AtwnlOE4cMvCEyXRBGCG6F4ryotvPeR8TdMTYneh+IkX1vxRr-IDekoxaWwH3IdeAoDBXw2AO5VWtw4jSyznoAA0piQ6WJNhEG+CuS84As7C1cCrdQW1Wa9vAH24WYsJbDGwNLZm1UF39sFoLdtfdO2A3uFS-aUE4A7qXYO8EI7wBjvIBOqdwYt1s0Xcu0W4tJYbsSKzWd86317oPX0cAigDgqy7RwHt07P3rqg+Ador5aGZrPCC4AiMW4x1pTKtiicPEKuMHh5VlBCN+L8CRqI2YaZ00EAa32RryzEy8K5CmZRKDgePT+hiWGZR6G2oGXm0Y+O+CFr05WURjYEBSEWYMRYjQKgk1J1KMnUpyeiAp8MrhAyqfE3iyT4VNO+HNplNBOrw6SFpY7LjCS7XTIdfmVZxZVlpT2VpYOvg3VmaQBZqOmHmK0cTmc1sFzbDp2gJnf+s4J1yD6LwQG1w-l7GPq1Yi0xJA3KSMuPacDjYhtagQC+BiIChAJBkMuCjmECEJGPcivIRV8kK+AaQ9w5CkE2JCJ5H12rLnKh29jO9L0Du+cO0d47oRPpnXOi9AGP1rqlj+l9A3APtF6xBk9Z6kDWAG9e4bd7RuTugwt6bq6v3Sz-VN3d+7luHtA4kPr3af3jZg3NhdwsENDCQ63LNEIGQ0ScQxYI2GMZKnIz6kHJUwdkzw1q62YK4D-fjgq3I+GdBGg0zGFH6rgyZlY3dyDnGqgA541zfjfMhMmhE1agngPFRwHyfwFCaFqQEAANqQAALrGfCaZ7KdtgiWap7a92OY4r2cWY5xZznQzbLCu5g5nm+ew-h16wLxhgt2CuWF64YJIlcqnjPNYyX2qpYvo1dyBBC7WC7rsIBg8G6oX+kQCdiuCcN2WLOShgJRhUp8IyrO1BRgAA4yWbFINYfEPQMhv215ydAkIlE0nVq2urQqxWOIlTHAP1PGwg-VBD-xefRJQ+AP0rKAfYcEDY6tsCGT0CZ-lsGJWNSvCo7JtjiSXOba19h9gAAXtoaQkbEiUDmRs5iSSUlYK2DXuv2TYDOGFpgVA9VRNA9pwUkR2rpAz0SKwMfDEZ8r+ViXyJWwx-JLGpP9J+-mLQbCCke-pfy96Hvykbfu+ZQVDE6vunP0KRzJP5sAkkZhUJRp3u0kgAHsGI-nmrwH3jRo7OfqklPtfvLNAPPjZh7HZt7P7EsvZM6i5kUDLiaFWOFsykFNQtfAltuJgokMmt0L0P0MCOwK3OdESuAAAJywA5h4DWzlzQppLbhx5bSkDqxQISajAICDiWAV5gBgiEjfDwqOLpDEApBsggCkAgCGLsHErBDsFaHBAgAeAB6NDErsHsG0oUTJ5WF2K-bp4MTsFZ7A4hL4bEbOHKr6gF4eHOEVAl5VDsHl6V4cYEA14OH16uDVKExmoiT1LBAVDt7apgE5TsH84YChGuxKwl6j7uiIGX4hE34N4v5ZT+EwEEDP737JgWxhw85OjJHK7JxBZpwa5HBdDl5FpvRhrbDoA8GYi6ygSQhjqW4nhfYjANZEhbBbRSISFSEyEgByHVSKG0TKGqF0LqGaHaG6H6GGHGGmHmFAYoCMqsBUpjT3DBEAAaegg0egigzg5x4Ahgzg+4IC06qo0gL20gc+wsWc223URApx4AdkbgEU4AeE3xI6LxbxHxk6oJRAg0-x7gQJIJdkNcKghgAA3AyB2jkWkn2iuMEY9mEOAMzgOgPPeo+mzrQPqC8WEGUNCXKISYzDsPwH2mzioFnESWzuADSXZI8f0CoH2lWMzqSWNhznsUejvDieQHibfoScSfwEKZOuSZSVEBUrSQSczgyQPMyayeyZyXCQOiYEgCAgKfKVnCKZiRPmklKc+izJeliVsBKVKfuitkES9sGHaekodnoLjvcA6S9oBkAA)

Answer (score 1):

Hmm, maybe you could try to create a function builder which will add default parameters for the function passed from elsewhere:

```
interface FooParams {
    a: number;
    b: string;
}

type FooParamsPartial = Partial<FooParams>;

type FooFunction = (args: FooParams) => void

const fooFun: FooFunction = (args: FooParams) => {

}

const defaults: FooParams = {
    a: 1,
    b: 'b'
}
const builder = (fooFun: FooFunction): FooFunction => {
    const withDefault = function (args: FooParams) {
        const newArgs = { ...defaults, ...args };
        return fooFun(newArgs);
    }

    return withDefault;
}

const withDefault = builder(fooFun);
```

Comment: Thank you! I have tried to adapt and shorten your solution to my scenario for better comparison. I find the function builder a bit confusing. But I was not aware of the {...defaults, ...args} thing! That simplifies a lot!