# typescript exclude optional fields from type

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

There is the Utility type `NonNullable` which will remove `undefined` and `null` values from a union type. But I was wondering if there was a way to remove optional fields from a type.

Basically if I have a type like this:

```
type MyType = {
  thingOne: number,
  thingTwo?: number
};
```

I want to be able to create a type out of the required fields only

```
type MyRequireds = NonOptional<MyType>;
// which is a type only containing "thingOne"
```

Is there some utility class that would satisfy the made up "NonOptional" utility class?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A tricky solution:

```js
type RequiredKeys<T> = {
  [K in keyof T]: ({} extends { [P in K]: T[K] } ? never : K)
}[keyof T];

type NonOptional<T> = Pick<T, RequiredKeys<T>>;

type MyType = {
  thingOne: number,
  thingTwo?: number
};

type MyRequireds = NonOptional<MyType>;
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=12&ssc=40&pln=1&pc=1#code/C4TwDgpgBAShCOBXAlgJwgEwNIRAZwB4AVAPigF4oBvAKCigG0spkA7KAa1wHsAzKIgF0AXFAAUVAL5QIAD2ARWGPNUYAFFuywiBTQVGkB%20KKwgA3CKiiisAShqSGXEHwGCA3DRqhIUAHLcrADyYMDIgQCGADbEZJRqyADGHMQANLAIKOjYuISkJJ7e4NAAsiBExRTUdFDAABZsAOZBpqKsiAC2AEaWqTX1TUQA7tyGbZ09qA6FPqUgcEhomCqUAcGh4azRBGUVkAU0QA)

The trick is that `{}` extends `{thingTwo?: number}` but doesn't extend `{thingOne: number}`. I originally found this solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49579497/4858777).

Comment: Can you expand this to include nested types? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71501126/typescript-exclude-optional-fields-from-type-deep

Answer (score 1):

You can compress this into one type using the bellow.

```
type OmitOptional<T> = { 
  [P in keyof Required<T> as Pick<T, P> extends Required<Pick<T, P>> ? P : never]: T[P] 
}
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/FAUwHgDg9gTgLgAjgTwiBB5AtgSzhiOHKAOwEMAbAHgBUA+BAXgQG8FgFOEBtABQRwkEAaxDIoAMwQAlEAEcArjhggAJrQZkAzgl44AxsNoAaXQ3BwQJVTtmLlaqnsMmzDAPy6EALgQkQAG4gMAC6vjR8IewAvsDAgpYwEmT66DQgWogsHFwQMFAQAIy+mTCCAOYA3DmceQUATO4lcGUkVcCxwChoCOmZdkoqqkyYuPiExOTUfXB01cD6pJkIUABGAFbhGXADDsPM2VwIdUW+AOSWmWemAPQ3CADusMI6EoIgNcf5EPXnl3BnTh3BDBfIwDpAA)

For nested types @lonewarrior556

```
export type OmitOptionalNested<T> = { [P in keyof Required<T> as Pick<T, P> extends Required<Pick<T, P>> ? P : never]: 
        T[P] extends (infer U)[] ? OmitOptionalNested<U>[] :
        T[P] extends object ? OmitOptionalNested<T[P]> :
        T[P] 
}
```

[Playgound](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/FAUwHgDg9gTgLgAjgTwiBB5AtgSzhiOHKAOwEMAbAHgBUA+BAXgQG8FgFOEBtABQRwkEAaxDIoAMwQAlEAEcArjhggAJrQZkAzgl44AxsNoAaXQ3BwQJVTtmLlaqnsMmzDAPy6EALgQkQAG4gMAC6vjR8IcAAvsCgkLCIKGiYuPiExOQUAHIgWpbq9EysPPyCImKSMvJKKoWaOs5GNKa85mCW1rY1DupNrm0eXr7+QaG+HFxTEbwhCBZWNggAFIISwQgAqgCU3HOe2HgERKSUufmOm3R7PpNTnDNzC10IUABGAFYg+ogHaceZM55Aq0SIMbx3e6PdixYCCSwwCRkfToGjA1iQiAwKAQACMvnyMEEAHMANyY7EQABM7gJcCJJDJMTi8OCSJRCHOBTR+QxUyxOPxCEJJPJ-MpNLpDKZU38F1U4WBkLlBQAgjAYIr8ntmcBkqjgXZampiod0icsrRgXRyfqEDy4EbelyTcwzQDTjlgY4XaoHXQ4vpSLz3h8hQ6nXViiwKYLfABySz5eOmAD0qYQAHdYMIdBJBCBY9SE0m4PHOOn5hrYLrKwAxWDCqBYdAqbSkJAAC3QWmQcDIYAQnZwxM7FBHnYRAh0pAoyGFnagmZJCAogRAFFeUhVJuC2JgCDIiDISBwLeAlYAQgpEHgszgKJv8g+n3AcQgg1gIA+VwoSERN0oTc7T3WAdDIFQEHzMA1GAIMSBDT4qS1R0ejqX1oyLIVE2BFMi2QhAcOTNMM1AmBlW9BU+XuTgBTxEtcOMSFxRxAiiLLBBKzIyFoiY2VKPVTUeGYrgYxomi6Ow0s8PE+46LY6TONI6tyNk2IpiiWEgA)

Comment: Can you expand this to include nested types? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71501126/typescript-exclude-optional-fields-from-type-deep