# typescript exclude optional fields from type (deep)

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings, typescript4.0

This is an expansion of this questions:
[typescript exclude optional fields from type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62050087/typescript-exclude-optional-fields-from-type)

If I have a type like this:

```
type MyType = {
  thingOne: { id: string; name?: string };
  thingTwo?: { id: string; name?: string };
};
```

I want to be able to create a type that only has the required fields in the object, aswell as anything nested inside of it.

ie.

```
type MyRequireds = NonOptional<MyType>;
/*
{
  thingOne: { id: string };
};
*/
```

is it possible?

TSPlayground link with shallow NonOptional
[TypeScripPlayground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAsiAq5oF4oG8BQUrABYEsA7AcwHlCIAudKfAE2oGdgAnI4gbikIEMBbCAH4mrdlAC+HLDgIl4AdwD2wmvRFsSXXgJXMNxCVPEYMoSFABKEAI4BXfCwh0A0hBCMAPPAB8UVJmwAbWdaQigAazdFADMoeABdagAKNHEoCAAPYAhCOkYaQIAFUKhnRLjg+IkoQW4IADcIFihqZwBKDHFAyJAYuPipUyQoADlFQlIwYHxxngAbL19UQvwAY3CvABpLG3tHFzdPH29Bs2g4KzsHJ3zUMYmpmd4FuERIE4wAegAqKEZcRS2OZ0KAAI2gGACMnY5CoqgYf1EJEMnSk30+GCAA)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With this recursive type:

```
type OnlyRequired<T> =
    T extends object
        ? { [K in keyof T as {} extends Pick<T, K> ? never : K]: OnlyRequired<T[K]> }
        : T;
```

If `T` is a primitive, we don't need to do anything. However if it is an object we have to go through each key and get only the ones that can't be optional (credit to @jcalz) and then recursively gets only required keys of `T[K]`.

Note that functions need a little special handling and checking for `undefined` is not exhaustive or the best way to check for optional properties but it does work for your example.

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBA8gdgGxAJQgRwK4EsBOEAmAPACoB8UAvFMVBAB7ARz4DOUA9gEYBWEAxsCgB+KAG8oAbQDSULHCgBrCCHYAzalACGbDMwiq5BWgyatq0gLrCocCADcIOKAC4oUi6-hJUmXARKW5AC+LtQA3ACwAFDRoJBQALIgxODQVKLRUFDAABZyAObwEK7iWPiuLMA4BWE2mgC2EEIVVQVQQZFRWbkFxADu7M1isuVQldVw+bVwDU0tE-ntnR3RsakaVF4o6Nh4REkpkKSdAPQnWVAAekJAA)

Comment: The check `{} extends Pick<T, K>` should work to determine if `K` is an optional property regardless of `undefined`, since `{} extends {foo?: string}` is true but `{} extends {foo: string | undefined}` is false.  Note that `undefined extends T[K]` is true for `T[K]` being `unknown` and `any`, so you might want to list that as a caveat (or [edit] to use `{} extends Pick<T, K>` instead)

Comment: Thank you! I updated my answer accordingly 

Answer (score 1):

For omitting optional fields from nested objects

```
export type OmitOptionalNested<T> = { [P in keyof Required<T> as Pick<T, P> extends Required<Pick<T, P>> ? P : never]: 
        T[P] extends (infer U)[] ? OmitOptionalNested<U>[] :
        T[P] extends object ? OmitOptionalNested<T[P]> :
        T[P] 
}
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/FAUwHgDg9gTgLgAjgTwiBB5AtgSzhiOHKAOwEMAbAHgBUA%20BAXgQG8FgFOEBtABQRwkEAaxDIoAMwQAlEAEcArjhggAJrQZkAzgl44AxsNoAaXQ3BwQJVTtmLlaqnsMmzDAPy6EALgQkQAG4gMAC6vjR8IcAAvsCgkLCIKGiYuPiExOQUAHIgWpbq9EysPPyCImKSMvJKKoWaOs5GNKa85mCW1rY1DupNrm0eXr7%20QaG%20HFxTEbwhCBZWNggAFIISwQgAqgCU3HOe2HgERKSUufmOm3R7PpNTnDNzC10IUABGAFYg%20ogHaceZM55Aq0SIMbx3e6PdixYCCSwwCRkfToGjA1iQiAwKAQACMvnyMEEAHMANyY7EQABM7gJcCJJDJMTi8OCSJRCHOBTR%20QxUyxOPxCEJJPJ-MpNLpDKZU38F1U4WBkLlBQAgjAYIr8ntmcBkqjgXZampiod0icsrRgXRyfqEDy4EbelyTcwzQDTjlgY4XaoHXQ4vpSLz3h8hQ6nXViiwKYLfABySz5eOmAD0qYQAHdYMIdBJBCBY9SE0m4PHOOn5hrYLrKwAxWDCqBYdAqbSkJAAC3QWmQcDIYAQnZwxM7FBHnYRAh0pAoyGFnagmZJCAogRAFFeUhVJuC2JgCDIiDISBwLeAlYAQgpEHgszgKJv8g%20n3AcQgg1gIA%20VwoSERN0oTc7T3WAdDIFQEHzMA1GAIMSBDT4qS1R0ejqX1oyLIVE2BFMi2QhAcOTNMM1AmBlW9BU%20XuTgBTxEtcOMSFxRxAiiLLBBKzIyFoiY2VKPVTUeGYrgYxomi6Ow0s8PE%2046LY6TONI6tyNk2IpiiWEgA)

Note: linters can sometimes only show one red squiggle at a time but it will break on compile saving you headaches

For the future, you can make almost any type a nested type by using the bellow template

```
type Basic<T> = { [P in keyof T]: T[P] }

type Nested<T> = { [P in keyof T]: // some logic to limit keys in object 
        T[P] extends (infer U)[] ? Nested<U>[] : // handles array
        T[P] extends object ? Nested<T[P]> : // handles objects
        T[P] // Same as in Basic<T>
}
```