# Derive a new interface from optionals where they are all required

Tags: typescript

How can I create a new interface based on optionals from another interface and make them required?

Say I have an interface like this:

```js
interface Foo {
  test1: string;
  test2?: string;
}
```

from this I'm looking to create a new interface that looks like this:

```js
interface FooDefaults {
  test2: string;
}
```

Then I can use that for my default values like this:

```js
const defaults: FooDefaults = {
  test2: 'bar'
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is tricky one, there is open discussion about syntax around that, take a look [here](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/35103). Below solution based on @jcalz [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49579094/typescript-conditional-types-filter-out-readonly-properties-pick-only-requir)

```
interface Foo {
  test1: string;
  test2?: string;
}

type Defaults<T, OptionalKeys extends keyof T = { [K in keyof T]:
  ({} extends { [P in K]: T[K] } ? K : never)
}[keyof T]> = {
  [K in OptionalKeys]-?: T[K]
}

type FooDefaults = Defaults<Foo>
```

I would say solution is more a hack than a solution and it based in the behavior where `{}` extends `{a?: string}` but `{}` doesn't extend `{a: string}`.