# Omit readonly property when mapping type

Tags: typescript, generics, types, mapped-types

I can't figure out a way to discard readonly props when mapping a type to another.

#### Scenario:

```
type SimplePOJO = {
    first_name: string;
    readonly last_name: string;
    year: number;
}

type Mapper<T extends SimplePOJO> = {
    [K in keyof T]: { name: K, type: T[K] }
}

// I also tried this without any luck:
//
// type Mapper<T extends SimplePOJO> = {
//    [K in keyof T]: T[K] extends Readonly<T[K]> ? never : { name: K, type: T[K] }
// }


type MappedPOJO = Mapper<SimplePOJO>
```

#### Desired outcome:

```
{
    first_name: {
        name: "first_name";
        type: string;
    };
    year: {
        name: "year";
        type: number;
    };
}
```

#### Actual result:

```
{
    first_name: {
        name: "first_name";
        type: string;
    };
    readonly last_name: {
        name: "last_name";
        type: string;
    };
    year: {
        name: "year";
        type: number;
    };
}
```

Is this possible with TypeScript?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a way to identify the writable keys and only keep them.

Example in the following [snippet](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#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)

```
type SimplePOJO = {
    first_name: string;
    readonly last_name: string;
    year: number;
}

type IfEquals<X, Y, A=X, B=never> =
  (<T>() => T extends X ? 1 : 2) extends
  (<T>() => T extends Y ? 1 : 2) ? A : B;

type WritableKeys<T> = {
  [P in keyof T]-?: IfEquals<{ 
    [Q in P]: T[P];
  }, { 
    -readonly [Q in P]: T[P];
  }, P>
}[keyof T];

type Mapper<T extends SimplePOJO> = Pick<{
    [K in keyof T]: { 
      name: K;
      type: T[K];
    };
}, WritableKeys<T>>;

type MappedPOJO = Mapper<SimplePOJO>;
```

Look at [@jcalz explaination](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49579094/typescript-conditional-types-filter-out-readonly-properties-pick-only-requir) for the `IfEquals` and `WritableKeys`

---

A simpler solution could be for you to specify the key to remove :

[snippet](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAyglgWzAGwgBQPICkNQLxQDeAUFGVAGZwBOAzsAPoB2AhghAFxT3VxMDmAblLlqEFgBMA9k2QgoyFvWZtO3YLwHDyUEOOpcmAVwQAjCNWEBfYqEhQAsizCRqAHgAqUCAA9gEJglaWEQUdGwMAD58KAwEOGA3Eh0AbQBpKD4oAGsIECkKKA8AXS5CKBEdVnYuNO0dKDs1D3Ti+rIrawAaKAByRWVqiF7I4VtwaCcXCAlMHBip1zd4JFQ5qMEgA)

```
type SimplePOJO = {
    first_name: string;
    readonly last_name: string;
    year: number;
}

type Mapper<T extends SimplePOJO> = Omit<{
    [K in keyof T]: { 
      name: K;
      type: T[K];
    };
}, 'last_name'>;

type MappedPOJO = Mapper<SimplePOJO>;
```

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for, thank you! Yes, the second option I was aware of, but was hoping to solve it in a different way (like you show me here) :)